# Is it necessary to use abc.ABC for each base class in multiple inheritance?

Tags: python, multiple-inheritance, abc

Consider the following code snippet:

```
import abc


class Base(abc.ABC):
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def foo(self):
        pass


class WithAbstract(Base, abc.ABC):
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def bar(self):
        pass


class WithoutAbstract(Base):
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def bar(self):
        pass
```

I have two questions regarding the code above:

1. Is it necessary to inherit `WithAbstract` from `abc.ABC` as well, or is it sufficient to inherit `WithoutAbstract` only from `Base`?
2. What is the pythonic way of going about it? What is the best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no *technical* need to re-inherit `ABC`, but some linters may complain and people may argue that a class with abstract methods should explicitly inherit `ABC` to make the intention clear that the class is still abstract, and not a mistake. This especially goes for cases like this, where you don't explicitly declare any obvious abstract methods:

```
class C(Base):
    def m(self):
        ...
```

Did you just miss implementing `foo` here, or did you intent to keep `C` an abstract class? Make it explicit by inheriting `ABC`.

Comment: Both answers from deceze and Jean-François Fabre pretty much sum up how to deal with `ABC` base classes. I voted this answer to be the "correct" answer, because it also includes some best practice thought concerning the explicit marking of an abstract class.

Answer (score 1):

`WithAbstract` inherits from `Base` which already inherits from `abc.ABC` so you don't have to inherit from `abc.ABC` again.

Unless all of a sudden `Base` ceases to inherit from `abc.ABC` and your code breaks.

I don't know about pythonic but I would tend to avoid multiple inheritance. True, it's not as problematic as in other languages like C++ but simple is better than complex.

If all the descendants of `Base` have to use `@abc.abstractmethod` decorator, then it's better to make it available from `Base` to avoid unnecessary copy/paste when creating a new child class.